# need to make the factory recovery after installing windows7

Tags: system-installation, laptop, hp

How can i recovery or restore my HP255 G1 as it issued from the factory if i replaced ubuntu 12.04 by windows7? ubuntu is the software install at the factory.
please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You can download Ubuntu 12.04, burn it into a CD/DVD/USB and install it. Look at the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

This Notebook was release by HP with **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** as an option (along with FreeDOS, or various Windows variants):

[chrisjrob (Blog) >> HP 255 G1 Laptop with Ubuntu](http://chrisjrob.com/2014/07/07/hp-255-g1-laptop-with-ubuntu/)

[Ubuntu hardware >> Ubuntu on HP 255 G1 Notebook PC](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201301-12662/)

While the Notebook is certified to run **12.04.2 (64-bit)**, you would be better off do a new install of Ubuntu **14.04 LTS (64-bit)** instead.

There are known issues with power management (under 12.04):

[Ubuntu forums > Laptop HP 255 G1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168021)